# Robolectric + Mockito - "Wanted but not invoked"

Tags: java, android, facebook, mockito, robolectric

I'm trying to learn `Robolectric` and `Mockito`, in order to achieve that i'm creating tests for an already working Android project. But i'm having some troubles. This will give you the idea of the Activity i'm trying to test:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public Session session;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        session = getActiveSession();
        if (session == null ) {
            // ...
        } else {
            if (sessionClosed()) {
                LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    public Session getActiveSession() {
        return Session.getActiveSession();
    }

    public boolean sessionClosed() {
        return session.isClosed();
    }

}
```

What this piece of code does, is to get the Active `Facebook` session and depending on the state of it, it shows a different `Fragment`. Now i'll show you the test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private ActivityController<?> controller;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private MainActivity spy;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
        activity = (MainActivity) controller.create().get();
        spy = Mockito.spy(activity);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed() {
        Session session = new Session(Robolectric.application);

        Mockito.doReturn(session).when(spy).getActiveSession();
        Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spy).sessionClosed();

        Mockito.verify(spy).getActiveSession();

        Fragment fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        Assert.assertTrue(fragment instanceof LoginFragment);
    }

}
```

As you can see i'm using Robolectric and Mockito in a separate java project. when I run the test class i'm getting the following:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mainActivity.getActiveSession();
-> at org.example.MainActivityTest.testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed(MainActivityTest.java:101)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

at org.example.MainActivityTest.testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed(MainActivityTest.java:101)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Could you please give me a hand with this?

**Edit**

I got rid of the ActivityController, to see if handling the lifecycle manually worked, but i'm getting the same "Wanted but not invoked" message:

```
@Test
public void testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed() throws Exception {
    Session session = new Session(Robolectric.application);
    MainActivity myActivity = Mockito.mock(MainActivity.class);

    Mockito.when(myActivity.getActiveSession()).thenReturn(session);
    Mockito.when(myActivity.sessionClosed()).thenReturn(true);

    myActivity.onCreate(null);
    myActivity.getActiveSession(); // works only if i call it manually

    Mockito.verify(myActivity).getActiveSession();

    Fragment fragment = myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    Assert.assertTrue(fragment instanceof LoginFragment);

}
```

However this time it says:

```
However, there were other interactions with this mock:
```

pointing to the `myActivity.onCreate(null)` line.

**Edit 2**

If use a spy, and call `onCreate()` on the spied Activity, like this:

```
private ActivityController<MainActivity> controller;
private MainActivity activity;
private MainActivity spy;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
    activity = (MainActivity) controller.get();
}

@Test
public void testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed() throws Exception {
    Session session = new Session(Robolectric.application);
    spy = Mockito.spy(activity);

    Mockito.doReturn(session).when(spy).getActiveSession();
    Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spy).sessionClosed();

    spy.onCreate(null);

    Mockito.verify(spy).getActiveSession();

    Fragment fragment = spy.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    Assert.assertTrue(fragment instanceof LoginFragment);

}
```

Then i get the following exception, pointing to the line `spy.onCreate(null)`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.getLayoutInflater(ShadowActivity.java:148)
at android.app.Activity.getLayoutInflater(Activity.java)
at org.example.MainActivityTest.testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed(MainActivityTest.java:109)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: It might be because you are spying *after* driving the non-spied Activity through its lifecycle methods...

Comment: How can I spy the activity and then drive it through its lifecycle using ActivityController?

Comment: I'm not sure - I found [this relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408484/robolectric-buildactivity-with-mockito-spy), but it has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your test.

- You're creating a spy, but not actually using it within your test.
- You're trying to verify that a method has been called, before calling the code that will cause that method to be called.
- You're never calling `onCreate`, which appears to be the method that you're trying to test.

Also, that stack trace doesn't match the code that you've exhibited - you're probably running an older version of your source.  You need to clean out your target directories and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But how can I use the spied Activity. I mean, how can I drive it through its lifecycle?. Should I use the old way of handling activities instead of ActivityController? The stack trace doesn't match because I only posted the relevant code.

Comment: Well, after you've set up your `doReturn` calls, and before you do your `verify`, you're going to have to call `onCreate` on your spied instance.

Comment: Even when I call `onCreate()`, I get the same "wanted but not invoked" unless I manually call `getActiveSession()` on the mocked activity. I don't understand why is not being call.

Comment: OK, can you update your question, to indicate how your code looks now?  Don't remove the original code - just add the new code down the bottom.

Comment: Done, I appreciate your help David.

Comment: OK, in your new update, you're using a mock, not a spy.  They're not the same thing.  With a mock, the methods all do nothing, unless you stub them to do something.  With a spy, the methods all do what they'd normally do, unless you stub them to do something different.  In this particular case, `onCreate` for your mock is doing nothing, because you haven't told it otherwise.  For what you're doing, a spy would make more sense than a mock.

Comment: ohh i see, i didn't know that. I switched to mock() because when calling onCreate() on the spied activity I was getting an exception (I edited the question). I found this https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/934 and i'm trying to figure out what is going on.