# Robolectric and Mockito spying Android Activity

Tags: java, android, testing, mockito, robolectric

This my second question related to Robolectric + Mockito. I've been struggling with this for a couple of days. What i'm trying to do is to spy an Activity to test its onCreate() callback method.

I don't know how to drive the spied Activity through its lifecycle in order to call onCreate(). This is my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public Session session; // Facebook session

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        session = getActiveSession();
        if (session == null ) {
            // ...
        } else {
            if (sessionClosed()) {
                LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    public Session getActiveSession() {
        return Session.getActiveSession();
    }

    public boolean sessionClosed() {
        return session.isClosed();
    }

}
```

And this is my attempt to test it:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private ActivityController<MainActivity> controller;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private MainActivity spy;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
        activity = (MainActivity) controller.get();
    }

    ...

    @Test
    public void testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed() throws Exception {
        Session session = new Session(Robolectric.application);
        spy = Mockito.spy(activity);

        Mockito.doReturn(session).when(spy).getActiveSession();
        Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spy).sessionClosed();

        spy.onCreate(null);

        Mockito.verify(spy).getActiveSession();

        Fragment fragment = 
            spy.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        Assert.assertTrue(fragment instanceof LoginFragment);

    }
}
```

However, when the test calls `spy.onCreate(null)` i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.getLayoutInflater(ShadowActivity.java:148)
at android.app.Activity.getLayoutInflater(Activity.java)
at org.example.MainActivityTest.testShowLoginWhenSessionClosed(MainActivityTest.java:110)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

And of course, if I don't call it, the `Verify()` fails because `onCreate` is no executed. So, Is this the right way to do it? how could spy an `Activity` using `Mockito` and drive it through its lifecycle?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm stuck in the same.

Answer (score 3):

There might be two solutions.

One:

In `setup()` method, replace `controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).attach();` instead of `controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);`

---

The other:

First, you should spy the activity correctly.
See my answer for spying a activity with `robolectric` in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867867/2011291)

Second, do not call `onCreate()` directly on spied activity, you should call `ActivityController`'s `create()`, in your case, call `controller.create()` instead of `spy.onCreate(null);`

Answer (score 0):

With Robolectric you have to call `controller.create();` to start the activity. After that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need call setup() before get():

```
controller.setup();
```

And if the controller instance is unnecessary, I highly recommend you to get Activity by following code:

```
activity = Roblectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
```

As we can see, the difference between these API is setup() and then get():

```
  public static <T extends Activity> ActivityController<T> buildActivity(Class<T> activityClass) {
    return ActivityController.of(shadowsAdapter, activityClass);
  }

  public static <T extends Activity> T setupActivity(Class<T> activityClass) {
    return ActivityController.of(shadowsAdapter, activityClass).setup().get();
  }
```

So the reason of your crash is setup():

```
  public ActivityController<T> setup() {
    return create().start().postCreate(null).resume().visible();
  }
```

it's a mock lifecycle, isn't it?

Finally hope this help you and someone else also need it.

Comment: But he needs to spy the activity and change the `getActiveSession()` method before calling `create()`